# Excel macro to save workbook on another session of excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Im trying to make a macro in one session of excel that saves a particular workbook in another session of excel.

Lets say i have Workbook1 and Workbook2 and i have opened them in different excel sessions.What i want is to make macro that saves  Workbook2 from Workbook1.

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried? This way, we can see where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a macro is stored in a specific workbook, every macro (or SUB) is aware of (and has access to) all workbooks that are open in Excel. Access to other workbooks is most easily obtained by using the [Workbooks collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841074(v=office.15).aspx) (`Application.Workbooks`) or by referencing a particular workbook by index (`Application.Workbooks(1)` or by name `Application.Workbooks("SomeWorkbook.xlsx")`. To [save a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585(v=office.15).aspx), you can use the `.Save` method of a workbook class.

To answer your question:

```
Sub SaveSomeWorkbook()
    Application.Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx").Save
End Sub
```

Comment: yes this works but if both workbooks are opened in one session of excel. if they are opened in different sessions of excel it gives me error "script out of range"

Comment: Can you describe/clarify how you open two sessions of Excel?