# How to Run macro in excel instance "2" from excel instance "1"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

Lets say i have already opened Workbook 1 in Excel instance 1 and Workbook 2 in excel instance 2

And i have macro called "AAA" in instance 1 and "ASD" in instance 2
i want to call "ASD" in instance 2 from "AAA" macro in instance 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel macro to save workbook on another session of excel](http://superuser.com/questions/801537/excel-macro-to-save-workbook-on-another-session-of-excel)

Comment: This is different. In this instance OP would like to execute VBA that is stored in a different workbook. In the link, OP was merely looking to save workbook2 from workbook1 and VBA was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is to use `Application.Run()`. As an example, I have a workbook named "SC Fun.xlsm" in order to run my `getData()` subroutine in that workbook, from another workbook, I can write:

```
Sub runAnotherWokbooksMacro()
    Application.Run "'SC Fun.xlsm'!getData"
End Sub
```